# amp-consent: dismiss box height when no consent obtained

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I have some trouble with  the data-block-on-consent attribute and the fact that as soon the user objects to the advertising and tracking activities the height of each affected Element is still present and shows an empty space defined by the height attribute of the Element.

```
<amp-ad .... height=100..>
```

The question is: How to get rid of this empty space when no user consent available?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's a button or some element which is being tapped to dismiss the consent/ad, amp-bind should be able to handle changing the height to zero since height is a bindable property. Something like this should work, changing out the button for your tapped element.

```
<amp-ad height="250" 
       [height]="adHeight[currentHeight]"
       ...>
</amp-ad>
<amp-state id="adHeight">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "noHeight": 0,
  "fullHeight": 250
}
</script>
</amp-state>

<button on="tap:AMP.setState({currentHeight: 'noHeight'})">Hide Ad</button>
```

Comment: thank you for the hint, but i doubt that this will work this way. Maybe if amp will enable mutliple events within one action. <button on="tap:consent.reject,AMP.setState..." > but this  is not allowed at the moment, anyway: upvote for your efforts.